# Excel: Sum The Values Other Than the Top Three in a Range

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, range

Using Excel I would like to get the total of the values in a range other than the top three values.

The range has #N/A values I would like to ignore.

The range in horizontal.

In  the case where as an example the top 4 values are all 8, I would only want three of the 8s to be excluded from the sum.

I have managed to sum the top three values in the range using the following function:

```
=SUM(LARGE(IF(NOT(ISNA(AW2:BH2)),AW2:BH2),{1,2,3}))
```

I assume there is a small adjustment I can make to the above, but my brain's not working.

Comment: why don't you sum over the entire range and then subtract the top Three sum with your formula above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `AGGREGATE` function to ignore the errors:

```
=AGGREGATE(9,6,AW2:BH2)-SUMPRODUCT(AGGREGATE(14,6,AW2:BH2,{1,2,3}))
```

> Function_num 9 = SUM
>
> Function_num 14 = LARGE
>
> Option 6 = Ignore errors

You will get an error if there are less than three values in the row.  You could trap for that with either `COUNT` or `IFERROR`  if that might be an issue.

Comment: Much better than mine!

Comment: @XORLX Thank you.  Too often, I don't think of the `AGGREGATE` function, since it is a relatively recent addition.

Answer (score 1):

**Array formula****:

`=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(AW2:BH2),IF(1-ISNUMBER(MATCH(AW2:BH2+COLUMN(AW2:BH2)/10^6,LARGE(IF(ISNUMBER(AW2:BH2),AW2:BH2+COLUMN(AW2:BH2)/10^6),{1,2,3}),0)),AW2:BH2)))`

Regards

where the values in the range `AW2:BH2` are assumed to of an order greater than 1E-6.

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*